# Mac Network Share via VPN Subnet conflict

Tags: macos, networking, router, vpn, network-shares

So we have a Windows Server 2008 hosting files and a VPN connection. One of my clients is at home, successfully connects to the server using the VPN, but can't access the network shares of the server. When i try to ping the server (192.168.1.250), it doesn't work. The VPN assigns IP in the range of 192.168.1.150 to .170. The client is currently at home, using his router and his local IP is in the same subnet (192.168.1.x). I'm really not sure as to why i cannot ping the VPN server, other MAC clients work just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: We have similar issues at my work, where our work network is 192.168.0.0/21 which covers a lot of residential router's default network address. We resolve most of these issues with our mac users by making the VPN the top most connection in the network connection settings (http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14006). Also "Send All Traffic" setting for the VPN doesn't work properly is OSX 10.8 or 10.9 from what we've seen here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have said it all: the two subnets, on either side of the bridge, are the same, so the poor router, when facing the task of sending a packet to 192.168.1.169 (say), does not know whether to use the WAN side or the LAN side. Most likely, it will use the LAN side, on which there may or may not be a 192.168.1.169, and the packet will be lost.

The only solution to that problem is to change the subnet of the VPN server to something highly unusual, (say, 192.168.237.0/24), so that the chances of a conflict between the two subnets become extremely small.

Comment: This is what i thought, sadly we can't change the VPN IP range lease but thanks for help nevertheless!